# How do I create a ".apk" bundle in .NET Maui android app

Tags: android, maui

I have created an app in .NET Maui using VS 2022 Community edition. I want to create a ".apk" package for the same. I changed the package type to ".apk" in the "Android" section of project settings. I changed the build type to "Release" from "Debug". When I build the application, I do not see any .apk anywhere in either Debug or Release folders.

I do not want a signed version of .apk. Just a simple barebones .apk.

What should I be doing or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"When I build the application"* - But did you "Publish"? That builds an archive. Which should then be listed when View Archives. Select it, click "Open Folder".

Comment: You can refer to this article about [Publish a .NET MAUI app for Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/publish-ad-hoc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I am using:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/publish-cli

The setup is quite long, and you need to follow the instructions precisely.

Pay attention to the signing part. Otherwise, even if you get your APK, you will not be able to install it on your device.

(After that you can make a bat file, and publish with one click)

Comment: I did not want a signed apk. I had already gone through that article. And yes, it works.

Comment: @MethodToChaos If it is not a company secret, what do you do with unsigned app? Do you give it to people who sign it later?

Comment: I am a beginner developer. This is a simple app that i have developed for my family members to exchange and share certain important information that is saved as appointments/schedule. Thanks.